# how to display loop times in playground

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I want to get the loop times info in playground. But it seems to only display the latest result for a loop on the right side. Do I miss anything? Xcode 15.0.1

```
import Cocoa

for i in 1...5{
    print("\(i)")
}
```

I have a screenshot:
[image]

EDIT:

Sorry for my poor English. I actually want to know how to switch the "5\n" to "(5 times)". I remember it used to display like that in the past. However, I can only switch in between "latest value" and "value history" for now. Is it changed because of the Xcode version. Or I'm looking in the wrong place

Comment: I just want to show the right-hand side info with gray shading on the screen for clarifying my issue.

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place. The `print` outputs appear at the _bottom_ in the Console.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Sorry for my poor English. I actually want to know how to switch the "5\n" to "(5 times)". I remember it used to display like that in the past. However, I can only switch in between "latest value" and "value history" for now. Is it changed because of the Xcode version. Or I'm looking in the wrong place

Comment: You cannot switch the "5\n" to "(5 times)". You know that it is 5 times because that is what your "5" means. If you want to know how many times you passed thru the loop, it is up to _you_ to count them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are importing `Cocoa`. With importing `Foundation` framework it works completely fine:

```swift
import Foundation

for i in 1...5{
    print("\(i)")
}
```

I see that you are not checking the output section in the bottom of the screen. Check my screenshot:
[image]

Comment: You are absolutely right. Sorry for my poor English. I actually want to know how to switch the "5\n" to "(5 times)". I remember it used to display like that in the past. However, I can only switch in between "latest value" and "value history" for now. Is it changed because of the Xcode version. Or I'm looking in the wrong place

Comment: I used mac OS playground blank template. So import Cocoa automatically

Comment: That’s fine. But Check the below debug console to check the output. Hope you got your answer.